# Asked to design a large banner.How should I start?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, ppi, billboard

I'm asked to design a large banner 10m * 4m. I'm not sure how should I start with Photoshop.
Should I create one with small size and high resolution? What is the number of PPI suitable for this size?

OR should I work with the actual size? If yes , Will Photoshop crash ? What is the number of PPI at actual size?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Besides reading that Q&A Cai mentions, asking your printer is also a great idea. They are probably going to tell you to design on scale, like 1:5 or even 1:10.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the dependence that answer your question. Vertical axe is the optimal image resolution and horizontal axe is the distance intended to look on the image. Red curve is for the people with myopia, green is for the people with normal vision and blue is for the hyperopia case.
Practically I never used for such big format the resolution more than 72 ppi.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up your file to scale, maybe 10:1
2. If possible, use vector graphics and not pixels
3. Use InDesign, or maybe illustrator. Photoshop is not a layout tool.
4. If you must use photography, 72ppi is a good guide for large scale outdoor imagery. Good design beats resolution every time.
5. Print out your design draft, tape it to your wall and stand back to review the design. This will give you a better feel for scale and how it will look from a distance.

Answer (score 1):

I already worked with large banners and you should not use Photoshop in this one. If you're going to manipulate photos or images, do it on Photoshop then proceed to work on your banner on Illustrator. If your banner requires a lot of text or reading I recommend InDesign. 
Large scale prints of photos needs higher definition but you can work between 60dpi and 150dpi. 
The software will not crash if you have enought memory on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the first answer, I would design to scale, and in Illustrator (especially if you will be incorporating a lot of graphics). But ask the printer what their setup preferences/delivery requirements are.